# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters when using national characters on getting file path

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, path, dockerfile

I got exception:

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: ZÉ LUIZ ALMEIDA SERÃO.pdf
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
        at org.someone.something.file.PathManager.createPathIfNecessary(PathManager.java:161)
...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I tried to:

```
Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(file));
```

I run project from dockerfile with params: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8

Please help me to find solution to fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [1] More information is needed. At a minimum, you need to update your question to show your code, and provide full details of your runtime environment (Java version, locale, language, default charset, etc.). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on improving your question. [2] Note that [assigning values to **file.encoding** and **sun.jnu.encoding** is unsupported](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400) on any Java release.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to Non-ASCII characters in file name & system is unable to resolve them. Here '**É**' & '**Ã**' in the file name are Non-ASCII characters. You can try renaming the file with ASCII characters only or you can escape the Non-ASCII characters in the string.